# Unlocking SCOTT user in oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, user-accounts, oracle19c

Trying to unlock SCOTT in oracle 19c.

```
 alter user scott account unlock identified by tiger;
```

ERROR Message:
ORA-01918: user 'SCOTT' does not exist

Comment: Is this a multi-tenant db?  If so are you attached to the cdb or a pdb?  Show the output of 'select username from dba_users order by 1'

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D):

Starting from **Oracle 12cR2**, only `HR` schema is provided via installation. All other sample schema scripts are available on GitHub at https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/releases/latest

`SCOTT` schema is no longer provided in the sample schemas, you could manually create it using the scripts from older Oracle versions or use the HR and other sample schemas.

Once you install the sample schemas manually in PDB, you could then unlock them and use. See **[Oracle Multi-tenant DB Post Installation Mandatory Steps](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/)**

Comment: Thanks Lalit. I'll try :P

Comment: @misaki Please mark it as answered, would help others too.

Answer (score 0):

In ORACLE 19C How TO CHANGE sysdba password.